# List column not displaying in the Siebel client server

Tags: siebel

I have added a already existing BC field to the list applet in order to display it in the list applets of the client. In the local machine it is working as expected.

But I need to move it to the server. 
First I checkout the relevant applet and did the changes. Then compiled and check in to the server.

But the field is not visible in the UI. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What Siebel version are you using?

Comment: Its 8.1.1.14.0, 11g

Comment: Once I checkout the specific object, I can see the field there as well. But not in the UI.

Comment: Have you compiled changes into the server SRF file after you checked in your work?

Answer (score 0):

You could try resetting the list applet layout in the client. Right click options. Also check if the field is added to the correct applet mode (Base, Edit). Under applet, check the mapping entries under the list column and see if any condition was added there.

Comment: It is working in the local client. But not in the server.